# Change color of overlapping convex hull

Tags: color, mesh, intersection

```
P0={0,0};
P1={1,0}; 
P2={-1,0}; 
P3={0,1};
P4={1,-1};
P5={-1,-1}; 
Framed[Show[Region[ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P3},MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[0.5, Red]}],PlotRange->{{-1.1,1.1},{-1.1,1.1}},Axes->True,LabelStyle ->{14,Bold}, ImageSize->Medium],Region[ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P3,P4},MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[0.5,Red]}], ImageSize->Medium],Graphics[Text[Style["Cone 1",20,Bold],{0.7,1}]]]]
```

I have this code where I show in a single plot the intersection of two convex hull. Now I know it is possible to change the color of individual hull's by changing the MeshCellStyle command. But is it also possible to change the color of the intersecting region without major changes in the code? This will help my reader to better recognize the intersection region when I plot many convex hull in a single plot.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chm1 = ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P1, P3}];
chm2 = ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P3, P4}];
```

You can use [`RegionIntersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) to get the intersection:

```
intersection = RegionIntersection[chm1, chm2];
```

and `RegionPlot` all three regions with different colors using the option `PlotStyle`:

```
Framed[RegionPlot[{chm1, chm2, intersection}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.5, Red], Opacity[.5, Blue], Opacity[1, Yellow]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, 
  Axes -> True, Frame -> False, LabelStyle -> {14, Bold}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, 
  Epilog -> Text[Style["Cone 1", 20, Bold], {0.7, 1}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very intelligent answer.